# Ruby implementation for Hacker Rank connected cells in a grid

Tags: ruby, interview-questions, matrix, depth-first-search

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/connected-cell-in-a-grid/problem

**problem statement:**

> Consider a matrix where each cell contains either a 1 or a 0.  Any
>   cell containing a 1 is called a filled cell.  Two cells are said to be
>   connected if they are adjacent to each other horizontally, 
>   vertically, or diagonally. In the following grid,  all cells marked X
>   are connected to the cell marked Y.
>
> XXX
>   XYX
>   XXX
>   If one or more filled cells are also connected, they
>   form a region. Note that each cell in a region  is connected to zero
>   or more cells in the region but  is not necessarily directly connected
>   to all the other cells in the region.
>
> Given an  matrix, find and print the number of cells in the largest
>   region  in the matrix. Note that there may be more than one region in
>   the matrix.
>
> For example, there are two regions in the following  matrix.  The
>   larger region at the top left contains  cells.  The smaller one at the
>   bottom right contains .
>
> 110
>   100
>   001

**my solution:**

```
# Complete the connectedCell function below.
def connectedCell(matrix)
    highest_count = 0
    visited = {}

    (0...matrix.length).each do |i|
        (0...matrix[0].length).each do |j|
        next if visited[[i,j]]
            if matrix[i][j] == 1
                res = get_area_count([i,j], matrix)
                if res[0] > highest_count
                    highest_count = res[0]
                end

                visited = visited.merge(res[1])
            end
        end
    end

    highest_count
end

def get_area_count(pos, matrix)
    q = [pos]
    visited = {}
    count = 0
    while q.length > 0
        tile_pos = q.shift
        if !visited[tile_pos]
            count += 1
            visited[tile_pos] = true
            q += nbrs(tile_pos, matrix)
        end 
    end

    return [count, visited]
end

def nbrs(pos, matrix)
    right = [pos[0], pos[1] + 1]
    left = [pos[0], pos[1] - 1]
    top = [pos[0] + 1, pos[1]]
    bottom = [pos[0] - 1, pos[1]]
    top_right = [top[0], right[1]]
    bottom_right = [bottom[0], right[1]]
    top_left = [top[0], left[1]]
    bottom_left = [bottom[0], left[1]]
    positions = [right, left, top, bottom, top_right, bottom_right, top_left, bottom_left]
    positions.select{|npos| in_bounds?(npos, matrix.length, matrix[0].length) && matrix[npos[0]][npos[1]] == 1}
end

def in_bounds?(pos, m, n)
    pos[0] >= 0 && pos[0] < m && pos[1] >= 0 && pos[1] < n    
end
```

**thought process:**
My thought was to iterate through each cell in the matrix and then if it was a `1` I would do a depth-first traversal to find all other cells that had a `1`and were connected to the parent cell. then I would add 1 to the count whenever I visited a cell and add it to the `visited` hash so that it wouldn't be added to the count. I added helper methods for `in_bounds?` and `nbrs`mostly for better readability in the `get_area_count` method(which is the dfs implementation). The `nbrs` method is pretty verbose, but I kept it that on purpose because I'm preparing for technical interviews, where accuracy is important, and I thought actually listing out each direction would help in debugging / explaining it to the interviewer.

Answer (score 1):

I really like clear and speaking method names, I quickly tried to refactor the first method but have had not much time, I hope this helps anyway.

I have not understand the other initialization of the `visited` hash in the area_count method (yet).

The new neighbors method indeed looks some kind of overloaded with information, no good idea yet how to change it, if needed at all as you described.

````
require 'json'
require 'stringio'

def connectedCell(matrix, visited = {})
    (0...matrix.length).each do |row|
        (0...matrix[0].length).each do |col|
        next if visited[[row, col]]
            if matrix[row][col] == 1
              return update_count_stats(row, col, matrix, visited)
            end
        end
    end
end

def update_count_stats(row, col, matrix, visited)
    result = area_count([row, col], matrix)
    visited.merge(result[1])
    result[0] > 0 ? result[0] : 0
end

def area_count(pos, matrix)
    q = [pos]
    visited = {}
    count = 0
    while q.length > 0
        tile_pos = q.shift
        if !visited[tile_pos]
            count += 1
            visited[tile_pos] = true
            q += neighbors(tile_pos, matrix)
        end 
    end

    return [count, visited]
end

def neighbors(pos, matrix)
    right = [pos[0], pos[1] + 1]
    left = [pos[0], pos[1] - 1]
    top = [pos[0] + 1, pos[1]]
    bottom = [pos[0] - 1, pos[1]]

    top_right = [top[0], right[1]]
    bottom_right = [bottom[0], right[1]]
    top_left = [top[0], left[1]]
    bottom_left = [bottom[0], left[1]]

    positions = [right, left, top, bottom, top_right, bottom_right, top_left, bottom_left]
    positions.select{|npos| in_bounds?(npos, matrix.length, matrix[0].length) && matrix[npos[0]][npos[1]] == 1}
end

def in_bounds?(pos, number_of_columns, number_of_rows)
    pos[0] >= 0 && pos[0] < number_of_columns && pos[1] >= 0 && pos[1] < number_of_rows   
end

number_of_rows = 4 # just for testing, was gets.to_i
number_of_columns = 4 # just for testing, was gets.to_i
matrix = Array.new(number_of_rows)

# sample input
# 1 1 0 0
# 0 1 1 0
# 0 0 1 0
# 1 0 0 0

number_of_rows.times do |i|
    matrix[i] = gets.rstrip.split(' ').map(&:to_i)
end
result = connectedCell matrix
puts result
```
````

Answer (score 1):

### Rubocop Report

#### connectedCell

Avoid nested code blocks if clean alternative statements are available. 
For instance, in method `connectedCell` you have the following block:

> ```
> if matrix[i][j] == 1
>   # .. code omitted
> end
> ```

Replace the if-statement with `next unless matrix[i][j] == 1` and you'll be able to reduce nesting with 1 level.

The next part has a similar avoidable nesting, only this time we can use an inline if-statement.

> ```
> if res[0] > highest_count
>     highest_count = res[0]
> end
> ```

This could be replaced with `highest_count = res[0] if res[0] > highest_count`.

And prefer to use *snake_case* for method names: `connected_cell`.

The complete method could then be written as:

```
def connected_cell(matrix)
  highest_count = 0
  visited = {}

  (0...matrix.length).each do |i|
    (0...matrix[0].length).each do |j|
      next if visited[[i, j]]

      next unless matrix[i][j] == 1

      res = get_area_count([i, j], matrix)
      highest_count = res[0] if res[0] > highest_count

      visited = visited.merge(res[1])
    end
  end

  highest_count
end
```

#### get_area_count

The while condition `while q.length > 0` should be replaced by `until q.empty?` because it's considered a negative condition (pseudo: `while !empty`).

We have another case of avoidable nesting: replace the `if !visited[tile_pos]` block with `next if visited[tile_pos]`.

The method rewritten:

```
def get_area_count(pos, matrix)
  q = [pos]
  visited = {}
  count = 0
  until q.empty?
    tile_pos = q.shift
    next if visited[tile_pos]

    count += 1
    visited[tile_pos] = true
    q += nbrs(tile_pos, matrix)
  end

  [count, visited]
end
```